# SwiftUI - Picker value not changing when accessing data from UserDefaults

Tags: swiftui

I am making an app where I am showing different views based of user's selection by a picker. The binding value of the picker is initially set by UserDefaults in a viewModel. The problem is when I choose a picker value in my app, The picker automatically go back to initial state, as if someone forcing the picker not the change the values.

Settings ViewModel :

```
import Foundation

class SettingsViewModel:ObservableObject{
    @Published var showSettings = false
    //Here is the problem
    @Published var choosenUserType = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userType"){
        didSet{
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.choosenUserType, forKey: "userType")
        }
    }
    
    
    static var userTypes = ["Client", "Worker"]
}
```

Home View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    @StateObject var settingsVM = SettingsViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            switch settingsVM.choosenUserType{
            case "Client":
                Text("This is client")
            case "Worker":
                Text("This is worker")
            default:
                Text("This is default")
            }
        }.navigationTitle("Tanvirgeek Co")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            settingsVM.showSettings.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("Settings")
        }))
        .sheet(isPresented: $settingsVM.showSettings, content: {
            SettingsView(dissmiss: $settingsVM.showSettings)
                .environmentObject(settingsVM)
        })
        
    }
}
```

Settings View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settingVM:SettingsViewModel
    @Binding var dissmiss:Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Picker(selection: $settingVM.choosenUserType, label: Text("Choose User Type"), content: {
                ForEach(SettingsViewModel.userTypes, id: \.self) { userType in
                    Text("\(userType)")
                }
            })
            
            Button(action: {
                dissmiss.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Dismiss")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? How to change the picker's binding variable value through the picked value here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `choosenUserType` ends up with an inferred type of `String?` because that's what `UserDefaults.string(forKey:)` returns.

The `Picker`'s selection type needs to match *exactly* with the tag type. The tags (which are inferred in this case as well) are of type `String`.

I've solved this by giving a default value to `choosenUserType` so that it can be a `String` (not `String?`):

```
class SettingsViewModel:ObservableObject{
    @Published var showSettings = false
    @Published var choosenUserType : String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userType") ?? SettingsViewModel.userTypes[0] {
        didSet{
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.choosenUserType, forKey: "userType")
        }
    }
    static var userTypes = ["Client", "Worker"]
}
```

Also, in your `SettingsView`, you don't have to interpolate the `userType` in the `Text` -- you can just provide it directly:

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settingVM:SettingsViewModel
    @Binding var dissmiss:Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Picker(selection: $settingVM.choosenUserType, label: Text("Choose User Type")) {
                ForEach(SettingsViewModel.userTypes, id: \.self) { userType in
                    Text(userType)
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
                dissmiss.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Dismiss")
            })
        }
    }
}
```